# Android: Broadcast receiver for any app launch or if any app comes to foreground

Tags: android, android-package-managers, activity-manager, applicationmanager

I have a service which has to monitor which application is in the foreground and based on the application do some functionality.

I can get the list of foreground applications, using `ActivityManager.getRunningAppProcesses()`. But with this I cannot monitor when the foreground application changes.

**ex.** when *Application 1* which was foreground goes to background and a new *Application 2* comes to foreground, the service should be notified about this.

Are there any Broadcasting happening in Android, so that my service can register to that and when there is a change in foreground application, the service gets a notification and can do the functionality as required.

Comment: AFAIK this can be done only by parsing `logcat` which, starting with KitKat, requires root.

Comment: That's ok. What do you mean parsing logcat? Will it consume much battery?

Comment: @caspase AFAIK `logcat` is just for development purpose!